# IIS reverse proxy rewrite encoded url segement (HTTP redirect)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I use IIS 10 as reverse proxy for hosting a webpage (3-party, I can not modify the code).

**Local: localhost:26982**

**External: sub.domain.com**

The external request is redirected to the local instance. I use the following rewrite rules (web.config) for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>      
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub.domain.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:26982/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>

            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                <add name="strict-transport-security" value="max-age=16070400" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When the user tries to log in on the page, it redirects to an OpenID provider (Steam - with HTTP302 - the return URL in the header). Unfortunately, the `return url` which is encoded in the path still contains `http://localhost:26982` (encoded as: `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26982`) and not `http://sub.domain.com`.
The request/redirect looks like follows:

https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26982%2Fsession%2Fverify&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26982&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select

This looks the same when I try it on `localhost` and it's working correctly. Never the less, when the auth success, the redirect is not working when using `sub.domain.com` for obvious reasons.

What is the correct method to decode => rewrite => re-encode URL path segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone also has problems with this, I found a working solution with some trial and error.

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Header" preCondition="IsRedirect">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Location" pattern="^https://(steamcommunity.com)/(.*)(return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26982)(.*)(realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A26982)(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{R:1}" pattern="steamcommunity.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="https://{R:1}/{R:2}return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsub.domain.com{R:4}realm=https%3A%2F%2Fsub.domain.com{R:6}" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsRedirect">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="3\d\d" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>

</outboundRules>
```

This will rewrite any HTTP 3XX redirects location with the new values.

If there is a better solution, let me know but for now, this works for me.